# How to express Kunen's inconsistency, Reinhardt and Wholeness axioms, by single sentences?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, embeddings

Working in $\sf NBG, $ can we express the property of a class being set theoretically definable, by a single sentence? Like for example, the following way:

$$\operatorname {std}(X) \iff \exists x_1 \in V,..,\exists x_n \in V \, \exists \phi:\\ X=\{y \in V \mid V \models \phi(y,x_1,..,x_n) \}
$$

The context for this question is that I'm trying to express the Kunen inconsistency theorem in one sentence. So, if the above is expressible by a single sentence in the class language, then one can easily express Kunen's theorem as:$$\neg \exists {\bf j} \, {\big (} {\bf j}: V \prec V \land [(V, \in, {\bf j}) \models {\sf ZFC}{\bf j}] \big{)}$$, where ${\sf ZFC}{\bf j}$ is $\sf ZFC$ with Replacement and Separation allowing the use of $\bf j$, and $\prec$ stands for *non-trivial elementary embedding*, defined as:

$$\begin{align} \ { \bf j}: V \prec V\iff & {\bf j} \subseteq V^2 \land \operatorname {total}({\bf j}) \land {\bf j}\neq [=] \, \land \\ & \forall P \, (\operatorname {std}(P) \land \operatorname {total} (P) \to P\hat|{\bf j} \subseteq P) \end {align}$$; where $\operatorname {total}(P) \iff \exists n \in \omega: \operatorname {preimage}(P)=V^{n+1}$; and
$R \hat|S = \{ \langle s_1,..,s_n \rangle \mid \exists r_1,.., \exists r_n: \langle r_1,.., r_n \rangle \in R \land \langle r_1,s_1 \rangle \in S \land ..\land \langle r_n,s_n \rangle \in S  \} $

Now, another approach is to add $``\operatorname {std}\!"$ as a primitive one place predicate symbol, and axiomatize that if $\phi$ is a set theoretic formula (i.e. has all quantifiers bounded by $V$) whose free variables are $y,x_1,..,x_n$, then we have $\operatorname {std}(\{y \in V \mid \phi\})$ if all $x_1,..,x_n$ are sets.

Using this, one can express Reinhardt and wholeness axioms by single sentences, as two different ways of circumventing Kunen inconsistency, as:

**Reinhardt:**$ \exists {\bf j} \, {\big (} {\bf j}: V \prec V \land [(V, \in, {\bf j}) \models {\sf ZF}{\bf j}] \big{)}$

**Wholeness:** $ \exists {\bf j} \, {\big (} {\bf j}: V \prec V \land [(V, \in, {\bf j}) \models {\sf ZC}{\bf j}] \big{)}$

> Is the first way possible? Is it equivalent to the second way?

> What other ways of presenting Kunen's theorem and those axioms by single sentences?

Comment: See Hamkins-Kirmayer-Perlmutter's "Generalizations of the Kunen inconsistency," starting at the last paragraph of page 5, here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1951.pdf